# I Need to upload the image _File to Google drive from Android app c#

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin, google-api

Hi i want to upload a image to google drive from my android app.

App take a picture and store it in:

```
public static File _file;
```

I want to upload _file to Google drive

I connect and I create a empty jpg file with this code:

```
`using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
using System.Data;
using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2;
using Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data;
using Google.Apis.Services;
using Google.Apis.Util.Store;
using Google.Apis.Upload;
using Google.Apis.Http;
using Android.Util;
using Android.Gms.Common;
using Android.Gms.Common.Apis;
using Android.Gms.Drive;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Java.IO;
using Google.Apis.Drive.v3;

namespace Fotonet
{
[Activity(Label = "Activity2")]
public class Activity2 : Activity, GoogleApiClient.IConnectionCallbacks, IResultCallback, IDriveApiDriveContentsResult
{
const string TAG = "Fotonet";
const int REQUEST_CODE_RESOLUTION = 3;

GoogleApiClient _googleApiClient;

protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

    SetContentView(Resource.Layout.prova2);

    Button button = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.myButton);
    button.Click += delegate
    {
        Activity1.Global.count = 2;

        if (_googleApiClient == null)
        {
            _googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
              .AddApi(DriveClass.API)
              .AddScope(DriveClass.ScopeFile)
              .AddConnectionCallbacks(this)
              .AddOnConnectionFailedListener(OnConnectionFailed)
              .Build();
        }
        if (!_googleApiClient.IsConnected)
            _googleApiClient.Connect();



    };



}

protected void OnConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result)
{
    Log.Info(TAG, "GoogleApiClient connection failed: " + result);
    if (!result.HasResolution)
    {
        GoogleApiAvailability.Instance.GetErrorDialog(this, result.ErrorCode, 0).Show();
        return;
    }
    try
    {
        result.StartResolutionForResult(this, REQUEST_CODE_RESOLUTION);
    }
    catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e)
    {
        Toast.MakeText(this, e.ToString(), ToastLength.Short).Show();
    }
}

public void OnConnected(Bundle connectionHint)
{
    Toast.MakeText(this, "Connesso a Google", ToastLength.Short).Show();
    DriveClass.DriveApi.NewDriveContents(_googleApiClient).SetResultCallback(this);
    Activity1.Global.count += 1;
    //StartActivity(typeof(MainActivity));
}

protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, Result resultCode, Intent data)
{
    base.OnActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_RESOLUTION)
    {
        switch (resultCode)
        {
            case Result.Ok:
                _googleApiClient.Connect();
                break;
            case Result.Canceled:
                Toast.MakeText(this, "Unable to sign in", ToastLength.Short).Show();
                Log.Error(TAG, "Unable to sign in, is app registered for Drive access in Google Dev Console?");
                break;
            case Result.FirstUser:
                Toast.MakeText(this, "Unable to sign in: RESULT_FIRST_USER", ToastLength.Short).Show();
                Log.Error(TAG, "Unable to sign in: RESULT_FIRST_USER");
                break;
            default:
                Log.Error(TAG, "Should never be here: " + resultCode);
                return;
        }
    }
}

void IResultCallback.OnResult(Java.Lang.Object result)
{
    var contentResults = (result).JavaCast<IDriveApiDriveContentsResult>();
    if (!contentResults.Status.IsSuccess) // handle the error
        return;
    Task.Run(() =>
    {
         var image = new FileOutputStream(App._file);

        //writer.Write("Stack Overflow");
        //writer.Close();
        MetadataChangeSet changeSet = new MetadataChangeSet.Builder()
               .SetTitle("Fotonet.jpg")
               .SetMimeType("image/jpeg")
               .Build();
        DriveClass.DriveApi
                  .GetRootFolder(_googleApiClient)
                  .CreateFile(_googleApiClient, changeSet, contentResults.DriveContents);
    });
}

public void OnConnectionSuspended(int cause)
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}

public IDriveContents DriveContents
{
    get
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public Statuses Status
{
    get
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
}
} `
```

How to fill this empty file?

Thank you!

When i try to upload it create an empty file jpg.

Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: in question title you ask how to upload file to google drive. But in question body you ask how to save screenshot into the file. So what is your real question?

Comment: I want to upload App._File. I think to to this: create an empty jpeg file and then write it. Do you have any idea how to solve? Do you know a best way?

Answer (score 0):

> How to fill this empty file?

If you just want to create basic picture file then use the following method:

```
private Bitmap CreateBitmap(int w, int h)
{
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.CreateBitmap(w, h, Config.Argb8888);
    int[] pixels = new int[w * h];
    for (int x = 0; x < w * h; x++)
    {
        pixels[x] = Color.Blue.ToArgb();
    }
    bitmap.SetPixels(pixels, 0, w, 0, 0, w, h);
    return bitmap;
}
```

And you can use the following codes to upload the image file to Google Drive:

```
DriveClass.DriveApi.NewDriveContents(client).SetResultCallback(new System.Action<IDriveApiDriveContentsResult>((result)=> {

            //Create MetadataChangeSet
            MetadataChangeSet metadataChangeSet = new MetadataChangeSet.Builder()
                .SetTitle("Test.jpg")
                .SetMimeType("image/jpeg").Build();

            var contents = result.DriveContents;
            //create the bitmap
            Bitmap bitmap = CreateBitmap(800, 800);
            //push the bitmap data to DriveContents
            bitmap.Compress(CompressFormat.Jpeg, 1, contents.OutputStream);
            IntentSender intentSender = DriveClass.DriveApi
                    .NewCreateFileActivityBuilder()
                    .SetInitialMetadata(metadataChangeSet)
                    .SetInitialDriveContents(contents)
                    .Build(client);

            StartIntentSenderForResult(intentSender, 2, null, 0, 0, 0);
        }));
```